# html form is not center when minimize the browser

Tags: html, css

Hello I have this issues with my code. So I got an HTML files that show the user information in a table format. The issues is when I have more than 4 tables row and try to minimize the browser the data does not stay in the middle it goes to a bit on the right side
[image]

However if I have only 4 rows of the data it will be in the center like this:
[image]

Here is the html code:

```html
<body>
<div style="width:100%; padding-top: 50px; margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto; text-align: center">
    <div class = "row">
        <div class = "col-md-3"></div>
        <div class = "col-md-6 text-center">
            <g:if test="${flash.message}">
                <div style="width:70%; border-radius: 5px; margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto;" id = "successMessage" class="message" role="status"><span>&#10003;</span>&nbsp;${flash.message}&nbsp;!</div>
            </g:if>
        </div>
        <div class = "col-md-3"></div>
    </div>
    <div style = "height: 50vh; width: 70%; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;">

        <div>


            %{--                        Table for customer client--}%

            <table class="table table-striped" id="table t1">
                <colgroup>
                    <col>
                    <col>
                    <col>
                    <col>
                    <col>
                    <col>
                    <col>
                    <col>
                    <col>
                    <col>
                    <col>
                </colgroup>
                <thead>

                <tr>
                    <th colspan="1" style="height: 40px;">
                        <h6 style="font-weight: bold; margin-left: 40px;">
                            <g:link action="index" controller="customer">All Customers</g:link>&nbsp;>>&nbsp;
                            <g:link id="${customers.id}" action="showCustomerClientById" controller="customer">${customers.name} Clients</g:link>&nbsp; >>&nbsp;${cus.clientName}
                        </h6>

                    </th>



                    <th colspan="1" style="height: 40px; text-align:right;">




                        <div style="display: inline-block;width: 100%" >
                            <g:link action="editCustomerClient" id="${cus.id}"><button id="edit" type="button"
                                                                                       class="btn"
                                                                                       style="font-weight: bold;color: white;background-color:#1f549c"><i
                                        id="add-icon" class="fa fa-edit" aria-hidden="true"></i>Edit</button></g:link>

                        </div>

                    </th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="5" style="height: 40px; text-align:center;background-color:lightseagreen"><h6 style="font-weight: bold">CUSTOMER CLIENT INFORMATION</h6></th></tr>
                <tr>

                <tr style="width:100%; height: 70px;">
                    <td style="width:50%; font-weight: bold; text-align: right;padding-right: 20px;">Name:</td>
                    <td style="width:50%; text-transform:capitalize; font-weight: bold; text-align: left;padding-left: 20px;">${customers.name}</td>
                </tr>

                <tr style="height: 70px;background-color: #f7fafd;">
                    <td style="width:50%;font-weight: bold; text-align: right;padding-right: 20px;">Client Name:</td>
                    <td style="width:50%; text-transform:capitalize; font-weight: bold; text-align: left; padding-left: 20px;">${cus.clientName}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr style="height: 70px;">
                    <td style="width:50%;font-weight: bold; text-align: right;padding-right: 20px;">Channel:</td>
                    <td style="width:50%; text-transform:capitalize;font-weight: bold; text-align: left; padding-left: 20px;">${cus.clientChannel}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr style="height: 70px;background-color: #f7fafd;">
                    <td style="width:50%;font-weight: bold; text-align: right;padding-right: 20px;">Channel ID:</td>
                    <td style="width:50%;font-weight: bold; text-align: left; padding-left: 20px;">${cus.clientChannelId}</td>
                </tr>

                <tr style="height: 70px;">
                    <td style="width:50%;font-weight: bold; text-align: right;padding-right: 20px;">Channel Access Token:</td>
                    <td style="width:50%;font-weight: bold; text-align: left; padding-left: 20px;"><div
                            style="width: 520px; word-wrap: break-word">${cus.channelAccessToken}</div></td>
                </tr>

                <tr style="height: 70px;background-color: #f7fafd;">
                    <td style="width:50%;font-weight: bold; text-align: right;padding-right: 20px;">Client Zendesk ID:</td>
                    <td style="width:50%;font-weight: bold; text-align: left; padding-left: 20px;">${cus.clientZendeskId}</td>
                </tr>

                <tr style="height: 70px;">
                    <td style="width:50%;font-weight: bold; text-align: right;padding-right: 20px;">Zendesk URL:</td>
                    <td style="width:50%;font-weight: bold; text-align: left; padding-left: 20px;">${cus.zendeskUrl}</td>
                </tr>

                <tr style="height: 70px;background-color: #f7fafd;">
                    <td style="width:50%;font-weight: bold; text-align: right;padding-right: 20px;">Zendesk API Auth:</td>
                    <td style="width:50%;font-weight: bold; text-align: left; padding-left: 20px;">${cus.zendeskApiAuth}</td>
                </tr>

                <tr style="height: 70px;">
                    <td style="width:50%;font-weight: bold; text-align: right;padding-right: 20px;">Zendesk API Token:</td>
                    <td style="width:50%;font-weight: bold; text-align: left; padding-left: 20px;">${cus.zendeskApiToken}</td>
                </tr>

                <tr style="height: 70px;background-color: #f7fafd;">
                    <td style="width:50%;font-weight: bold; text-align: right;padding-right: 20px;">Status:</td>
                    <td style="width:50%;text-transform:capitalize;font-weight: bold; text-align: left; padding-left: 20px;">${cus.status}</td>
                </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Any ideas what going on here?
Many thanks.

Comment: Your code would be a lot easier for us to read if you formatted it better and replaced the inline styles with classes

Comment: The root of your poblem is : ` <div style="width: 520px; word-wrap: break-word">${cus.channelAccessToken}</div>`, this will call problems when screen width is < 520 * 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `display: flex; align-items: center;` to every `tr`

Answer (score 0):

I may assume that you need to set `width: max-content` to your  tables container and then center it using

```
margin-left: 50%; 
transform: translateX(-50%);
```

and then to center the very table inside it, and set to the table elements(`td`...)

```
text-align: center;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I tried the width:max-content and the table is in the center but it is not responsive. Any ideas how to make it responsive?

Comment: You can specify any units `%`, `vw`, `px`, it does not have to be exactly `max-content`